# Custom taxonomy labels won't display

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I created two custom taxonomies (Majors and Seminar Types) related my custom post type CEMB Seminar and the labels on the menu, instead of showing the labels I put in are showing "Post Tags".

See a screenshot here (I don't have enough reputation to post pics yet): https://picasaweb.google.com/112518288555484095597/WordPressIssues?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCNeKmKmS2J_ccQ&feat=directlink

Here's the code I used to create the custom taxonomies:

```
// Register the Majors taxonomy
register_taxonomy( 'cemb_seminar_major', array( 'cemb_seminar' ), $major_args );

// Register the Seminar Types taxonomy
register_taxonomy( 'cemb_seminar_type', array( 'cemb_seminar' ), $types_args );

// Set up the Majors arguments
$major_args = array( 
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'major',
        'with_front' => 'false'
    ),
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Majors',
        'singular_name' => 'Major'
    )       
);

// Set up the Types arguments
$types_args = array( 
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'seminar-type',
        'with_front' => 'false'
    ),
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Seminar Types',
        'singular_name' => 'Seminar Type'
    )
);
```

I thought maybe since I didn't include all the labels, it wasn't creating the labels correctly, so I later added:

```
'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Majors', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Major', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Majors' ),
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Majors' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Majors' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Major' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Major' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Major' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Major' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate majors with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove majors' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most popular majors' )
        )
```

and

```
'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Seminar Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Seminar Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Seminar Types' ),
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Seminar Types' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Seminar Types' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Seminar Type' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Seminar Type' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Seminar Type' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Seminar Type' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate seminar types with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove seminar types' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most popular seminar types' )
        )
```

But neither changed helped.  I noticed my custom post type also didn't have all the labels customized, so I added the labels to that code and the menu changed to reflect the newly added labels, but the custom taxonomies won't do that.  What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your args need to be defined before registering the taxonomies, that is most definately your issue if the args are being defined after - as in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `'labels'` to an array arg, and passing that. Also, check for syntax:

```
$labels => array(
    'name' => _x( 'Seminar Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Seminar Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Seminar Types' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Seminar Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Seminar Types' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Seminar Type' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Seminar Type' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Seminar Type' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Seminar Type' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate seminar types with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove seminar types' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most popular seminar types' )
);
// Set up the Types arguments
$types_args = array( 
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'seminar-type',
        'with_front' => 'false'
    ),
    'labels' => $args
);
// Register the Seminar Types taxonomy
register_taxonomy( 'cemb_seminar_type', array( 'cemb_seminar' ), $types_args );
```

Comment: Thanks for that Chip.  Actually, it appears that I had the register_taxonomy statement above the variables with all the labels in it.  When I put the register_taxonomy statement below the variables, the labels now appear correctly.  Thanks again for the help, you gave me the idea to look there.

Comment: Ah, so it was syntax (sort of) after all. Note that, while hooks can be called before their callback functions, I don't think the same is generally true for variables - especially argument arrays, c.f. `comment_form()` - passed to other functions.